# String comparisons and if statements

Tags: perl

I am doing an assignment which asks to search for a user in a file using the `passwd` file in `/etc`.

I was able to do that, but when it cannot find a specific user it doesn't reply with the print command I have used.

Here is my code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file = '/etc/passwd.bak'
open ( FILE, $file ) or die "Error in reading file. Program will close";

while ( <FILE> ) {

    chomp;
    @field = split ( ':', $_ );

    if ( $ARGV[0] eq $field[0] ) {
        print "User ID: $field[2]\n" ;
        print "Home Directory: $field[5]\n";
    }
    elsif ( @ARGV[0] ~= $field[0] {
        print "User: $ARGV[0] does not exist.\n"
    }
    elsif ( (@ARGV > 1 || @ARGV == 0 ) ) {
        print "Please enter one argument only.\n";
        exit 0;
    }
}
```

I have tried exchanging the `!=` for `ne`, but when I do that it says every argument is not found even when I know it is there.

I have tried to look in my book, and research it online with no luck.

Comment: `@ARGV[0]` won't work because `ARGV[0]` is a scalar, not an array.  You probably meant `$ARGV[0]` as you used in the first check.  Also, you appear to be missing a close paren after `$field[0]`.  Consider adding `use warnings;` to the top of your script.

Comment: I will try that, thank you

Comment: Are you clear that `while ( <FILE> ) { ... }` will execute the block once for each line in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually parameter checking happens at the beginning, not in a loop.

You can say that the user does not exist only after the loop.

You should use $ARGV[0] instead of @ARGV[0].

I've tried to make the program to do what you described:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if ((@ARGV > 1 || @ARGV == 0)) {
        print "Please enter one argument only.\n";
        exit 0;
}

$file = '/etc/passwd';
open( FILE, $file ) or die "Error in reading file. Program will close";
$found =0;
while ( <FILE> ) {
        chomp;
        @field = split ( ':', $_ );

        if ($ARGV[0] eq $field[0] ) {
                print "User ID: $field[2]\n" ;
                print "Home Directory: $field[5]\n";
                $found = 1;
        }
}
if ($found == 0) {
        print "User: $ARGV[0] does not exist.\n"
}
```

Comment: When I typed in the code, it still happens the same way. The print is not displayed if the user is not found.

Comment: Maybe you have mistyped something.  $found is set to 0, then it will be changed to 1 only if the user has been found. At the end it will print if  $found is 0. I've tested it. It works for me. Your version has not worked because there were several errors, missing semicons, @ARGV[0] instead of $ARGV[0], missing ")", "~=" instead of "ne".

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `ne` is the correct operator for comparing if strings are not equal.  You probably meant `$field[0] ne $ARGV[0]`.

Aside from that, your code has some structural issues.  Firstly, you check parameter counts inside of your file reading `while` loop.  Parameter checks should be the first thing a script does, not something it does while processing.  Secondly, because the "does not exist" check is inside the while loop, you'll output that message for every line that isn't the user.  If your input file has 100 lines and one is your search target, you'll output one match message and 99 "does not exist" message.

I would suggest a structure like the following.  Because this is for homework and should be a learning experience, I'm only giving you pseudocode, not usable perl.

```
if ( wrong_param_count ) {
    print "error message"
    exit
}

found_user = 0
while ( read_line_from_file ) {
    if ( this_line_is_user ) {
        print "user information here"
        found_user = 1
    }
}

if ( !found_user ) {
    print "user not found"
}
```

Comment: So I am VERY new to PERL. I havent used it before this class at all. Alrighty, so I tried to structure it following your pseudocode. But it gives me error messages

Comment: Alrighty it was because I forgot to add the $. Let me try it now

Comment: @user4839691: It takes common sense, not a knowledge of Perl, to realise that you shouldn't be checking the number of parameters every time you read a line from the input file, or that you must read to the end of the file before you can know whether the user was found or not. What languages do you know?

Comment: I am still learning all the languages. I just started learning JAVA.